# Gridview Edit All Rows that are checked in .NET / C

Tags: c#, gridview

What I am trying to do is, When the checkbox on the grid gets checked then the row will open up ready to be edited. I have tried:

```
    grdEditing.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;  
    BindData();
```

I did try other code and nothing would work. Is this even possible?

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdEditing" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EmptyDataText="N/A" DataKeyNames="ID">
    <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID = "chkAll" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox id="chkSelect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" Visible="false" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="JobCode" HeaderText="Job Code" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="JobTitle" HeaderText="Job Title" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DeptID" HeaderText="Dept ID"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Department" HeaderText="Dept Desc"/>
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

[image: Layout of what it looks like.]